# Am I eligible to take up PMP

Tags: pmp

I am working in that IT service industry, with 5.6 years of experience.  I was involved in many projects, of very small duration (less then 2 months),  even though i understand the basics of project management, and has a experience of handling such projects, Am I eligible to take up PMP certification?

Thanks,
Veena

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evidences and experience letter for PMP](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/evidences-and-experience-letter-for-pmp)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the PMI page with a [list of the requirements](http://www.pmi.org/en/Certification/Project-Management-Professional-PMP.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For me it more like a philosophical question. When I first read your question and answered I got the impression that you are not ready yet. @David pointed out that **there is a difference between being ready and being eligible**. For me, being ready is a higher state of mind than being eligible, and for an unknown reason I had *ready* in my mind not *eligible*.

I'm pretty sure there is a site - see @Mark's answer - which provides you the minimum requirements for starting the certification process. Based on your details you may have the necessary experience to start, so you seem to be eligible. However I don't know whether it is enough to get the certificate. It is like *schrodinger's cat*: **you won't know until to go there and start the process**. I'm pretty sure that these processes cost a lot of money and more importantly take a lot of your time. So check whether you are ready - dedicate enough - to carry through.

Comment: I think Veena was asking if she was eligible, not ready.

Comment: I see what you mean, I think I was a bit quick and judgmental. I'll rephrase my answer. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1):

It appears "being involved" or being responsible for specific work packages is no longer sufficient; you have to prove that you were indeed the assigned project manager.

See the post [here](http://pmstudent.com/pmp-eligibility-requirements-changed-on-april-17-2012/) on PM Student for more info.

If you spent 4500 (or 7500 depending on your degree) managing projects during those 5.6 years, then you can apply. Note that some PM training hours are also needed to apply; just understanding PM concepts might not be sufficient.